# Request JSON not mapping automatically to DTO or VO Object

Tags: json, spring-boot

I have spring boot application. I am trying to save a simple Hospital details JSON request but when I check the on the server side the JSON is not mapped to VO object. It always comes as null.

Code:
pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.company.tracker</groupId>
    <artifactId>hospitals</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>HealthCareApp</name>
    <description>Spring boot for hopitals</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- OAuth2 Client -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId> 
            </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JWT library -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.22.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.22.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass> com.company.tracker.hostipals.HealthCareAppApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

HospitalDetailsVO.java

```
    package com.company.tracker.hospitals.vo;

import java.io.Serializable;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class HospitalDetailsVO  extends AuditVO implements Serializable{

    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -759883774566026493L;


    private Long hospitalId;
    
    
    private String registrationId;
    

    private String hospitalName;
    
    
    private String address1;
    
    
    private String address2;
    
    
    private String address3;
    
    
    private String streetName;
    
    
    private String landmark;
    
    
    private String city;
    
    
    private String district;
    
    
    //private ZipCodeMasterData zipcode;
    
}
```

AuditVO.java

```
    package com.company.tracker.hospitals.vo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Data
public class AuditVO implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1781884768898596479L;

    private String createdBy;

    private String creationDate;

    private String lastModifiedBy;

    private String lastModifiedDate;

    private String isDeleted;
}
```

Controller:

```
    package com.company.tracker.hostipals.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.company.tracker.hospitals.entity.HospitalDetails;
import com.company.tracker.hospitals.vo.HospitalDetailsVO;
import com.company.tracker.hostipals.service.HospitalInformationService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/hospital")
public class HospitalDetailsController {

    @Autowired
    HospitalInformationService hospitalInformation;

    @PostMapping(value = "/registration", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public String hospitalRegistration(@RequestBody HospitalDetailsVO hospitalRegistration) {
        return hospitalInformation.createHospital(hospitalRegistration);

    }

    
}
```

Request JSON:

```
"hospitalId":null,
"registrationId":1233,
"hospitalName":"Bharathi mithulan hospital",
"address1":"O.Nanjagoundanpalayam",
"address2":"Odathurai",
"address3":"Erode",
"streetName":"Bhavani TK",
"landmark":"Srinivasa Rice mill opposite",
"city":"Erode",
"district":"Tamilnadu",
"createdBy":"bharathi",
"creationDate":"5-11-2020",
"lastModifiedBy":"bahrathi",
"lastModifiedDate":"5-11-2020",
"isDeleted":"N"
}
```

When pass the above JSON the value received on controller is coming as null for all the object valuesa highlighted below.

[image]

Can I know where I am making msitake in mapping the request JSON to VO object.

Comment: What is inside the class AuditVO ? . Perhaps some of the base class attributes expected is not proper ? class HospitalDetailsVO  extends AuditVO

Comment: @jafarmlp added the AuditVO class as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. The lombok getter and setter not get generated.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to examine the raw data first to see what is reached at the backend.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/registration", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public String hospitalRegistration(@RequestBody String data) {
       //print the data
    }
```